# Python code loop speed comparisons

Tags: python, numpy

Why does this line of Python

```
yy = [sum(y[i:i+5])/5. for i in range(len(y)-4)]
```

run some 20 times faster than the following (equivalent) code?

```
for i in xrange(0,len(y)-4):    
    yy = np.append(yy, sum(y[i:i+5])/5.)
```

Where y is a large array of reals. 
What actually is going on under the hood here?
Many thanks.

Comment: You can still use xrange in the first example, might speed it up a bit more.

Comment: List comprehensions tend to be faster than loops. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2849645/in-python-is-it-better-to-use-list-comprehensions-or-for-each-loops

Comment: What do you mean when you say these are equivalent? In looking at NumPy's `append`, it calls NumPy's `concatenate` which at the very least does extra checking for masked arrays. Additionally, appending to arrays is often more expensive, so I'm not sure that this result is counter-intuitive.

Comment: add `numpy` to the tags, this has as much to do with numpy as it does with python.

Comment: @EMS The extra checking doesn't add much overhead. The problem is that using `numpy.append` makes the algorithm `O(n^2)`, while python `list`s have `O(n)` performances when doing sequences of `append`s.

Answer (score 3):

The two codes are **not** equivalent. The correct equivalent version is:

```
yy = []
for i in range(0,len(y)-4):    
    yy.append(sum(y[i:i+5])/5.)
```

Which takes about the same time:

```
In [10]: y = [1.0] * 100000

In [11]: %timeit [sum(y[i:i+5])/5. for i in range(len(y)-4)]
10 loops, best of 3: 49.6 ms per loop

In [12]: %%timeit yy = []
    ...: for i in range(0,len(y)-4):    
    ...:     yy.append(sum(y[i:i+5])/5.)
    ...: 
10 loops, best of 3: 55.1 ms per loop
```

The problem is the call to `numpy.append` which is much slower than `list.append`.
This is probably due to the fact that `numpy.append` is creating *a copy* of the array and returning it *for every insertion*. 
The first insertion costs `2`(allocate space for 1 element and copy it there). The seconds costs `3`(allocate space for 2 elements, copy the lone element and the new one). The third costs `4`(allocate for 3, copy 2 elements and the new one). etc.

This means that **the algorithm suddenly became `O(n^2)`, while it is `O(n)` using python `list`s** since they do **not** copy the whole list for every `append`. They are smart enough to allocate more memory to accommodate more elements.

Also, as a general rule, `numpy` does **not** shine for single-element accesses. It's actually *slower* than pure python in that case, because it has to convert between machine data types and python objects all the time. Try to vectorize the operations and you'll see big speed ups.

Answer (score 3):

numpy is designed to perform vectorized operations: if you have to keep calling `numpy.append`, the overhead of each call will make it not worth the while.

The right way to do this operation (rolling means) in `numpy` is to vectorize it, for example using the convolve function (thanks to @askewchan for the suggestion). In that case it is *far* faster than the list comprehension:

```
import timeit
import numpy as np

y = np.random.normal(0, 1, 10000)

print timeit.timeit("np.convolve(y, np.ones(5)/5, mode='valid')",
                    setup = "from __main__ import y; import numpy as np",
                    number=100) 

print timeit.timeit("[sum(y[i:i+5])/5. for i in range(len(y)-4)]",
                    setup = "from __main__ import y",
                    number=100)
```

On my machine, 100 iterations of the numpy vectorized solution takes 0.03 seconds, while the list comprehension takes 6.56 seconds.

Comment: That's a really cool but complicated way to do a rolling mean, it only has to be so fancy to be able to do a function like `std`.  For `mean`, one easy (and actually, faster) solution is `np.convolve(a, np.ones(5)/5, mode='valid')`

Comment: @askewchan: Excellent idea: I've changed my solution to use convolve

Comment: `np.correlate(y, np.ones(5)/5)` is another alternative. I timed it, and it is tiny bit faster than `convolve` method on my machine.

Comment: The main reason for me rolling my own rolling mean and not use np.convolve(), was to to exactly reproduce the output of Matlab's curve fitting smooth() function.

Comment: @DavidHardwick in what situation does `np.convolve` not give the same answer as your rolling window approach?