# Pythonic way to calculate the mean and variance of values in Counters

Tags: python, performance, counter

I'm wondering whether there is a Pythonic way to compute the means and variances of Counters?

For example, I have four Counters sharing the same keys:

```
a = Counter({1: 23, 2: 39, 3: 1})
b = Counter({1: 28, 2: 39, 3: 1})
c = Counter({1: 23, 2: 39, 3: 2})
d = Counter({1: 23, 2: 22, 3: 1})
```

My way to do that is:

```
each_key_val = {}

for i in a.keys():  # The assumption here is that all Counters must share the same keys
    for j in [a, b, c, d]:
        try:
            each_key_val[i].append(j[i])       
        except:
            each_key_val[i] = [j[i]]
```

I could use the following code to find the mean / variance for each key:

```
 np.mean(each_key_val[i])
 np.var(each_key_val[i])
```

Is there an easier way to compute the mean / variance for each key compared to my way?

Comment: what version of python?

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham `2.7` But I'm willing to accept any suggestions regardless of the version of Python :)

Comment: You can create the dict using a defaultdict  which would be much simpler, what do you want to do with the mean and variance?

Comment: what about np.mean([counterName].values()) ?

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham Oh yeah that works! Thanks for the good suggestion!

Comment: No worries, FWIW using >= python3.4 you could also use statistics.mean and statistics.variance. You can also use  `for k, v in d.items():` http://pastebin.com/HCTpYEuf

Comment: You can also map this over all your Counters with a nice one liner:
`map(lamdba v: np.mean(v.values()),[a,b,c,d])` or both operations at once as a list of tuples:
`map(lambda v: (np.mean(v.values()),np.var(v.values())),[a,b])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not that I think the following is more readable than what you have, but it only uses list comprehensions.

Say you have

```
cs = (a, b, c, d)
```

Then a dictionary of the mean can be found with

```
m = {k: float(d) / len(cs) for k, d in sum(cs).iteritems()}
```

For the variance, note that, by the [definition of variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Definition) *V[X] = E[x<sup>2</sup>] - (E[X])<sup>2</sup>*, so, if you define:

```
p = sum([Counter({k: ((float(d**2) / len(cs))) for (k, d) in cn.iteritems()}) \
     for cn in cs])
```

then the variance dictionary is

```
{k: p[k] - m[k]**2 for k in m}
```

Comment: So does using only list comprehensions make the computation faster?

Comment: List comprehensions are usually a bit faster than for loops; YMMV, and I doubt it will change much here. I think the point is different (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2849645/in-python-is-it-better-to-use-list-comprehensions-or-for-each-loops)) - it's considered by some more Pythonic to use loops for stuff that does side effects, and build data structures, to the extent possible, using list comprehension. Some  consider this distinction clears up the code. Not only is this a per-case question, there's also room for personal taste.