# Fast subset sublists in Python

Tags: python, list, loops, subset

I have a list of sublists that has thousands of records.
A sample from the list is this:

```
list_full = [
    [343, 354,"Sometext1", "Sometext2", "Sometext3"],
    [43543, 345435,"Sometext1", "Sometext2", "Sometext3"],
    [4354, 54354,"Sometext1", "Sometext2", "Sometext3",
         "Sometext4", "Sometext5"]
]
```

I want to subset this main list into two separate lists. The first list should have each first two records from the sublists, and the second one, the remaining records.
As an example, I need them stored as:

```
list_a = [[343, 354], [43543, 345435], [004354, 54354]]
list_b = [["Sometext1", "Sometext2", "Sometext3"], ["Sometext1", "Sometext2", "Sometext3"], ["Sometext2", "Sometext3", "Sometext4", "Sometext5"]]
```

I have the following script:

```
list_1 = []
list_2 = []

for item in list_full:
    list_1.append(item[:2])
    list_2.append(item[2:])
```

But uses loops and is kind of slow. Is there a faster way to perform this list subset? Thanks!

Comment: From your problem statement looks like you are workig with some kind of structured data. I would suggest having a look at pandas library, as it seems like a potential iteresting library for the long term. It would allow you to perform slicing, indexing and many more features.

Comment: I think your current approach is just fine, other possible approaches (such as list comprehensions or `map`) will require iterating over the `list_full` twice rather than once

Comment: Thank you for the tips. List comprehension appears to be faster though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it lazyly with `itertools`:

```
import itertools

list1 = itertools.imap(lambda x: itertools.islice(x, 0, 2), list_full)
list1 = itertools.imap(lambda x: itertools.islice(x, 2, None), list_full)
```

This way the computation will not be evaluated until you require it. Notice that if you want it to be evaluated instantly you can call a `list()` to transform the itertools object into a list.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. On a small subset of data I found the list comprehension as faster.

Comment: @Litwos, yes, for small data itertools will be slower maybe, but think about it when you have huge amounts :)

Comment: I tested again on a bigger subset and it's faster than list comprehension. thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
# to create two lists
list_1 = [x[:2] for x in list_full]
list_2 = [x[2:] for x in list_full]

# to create two generators, supporting iteration (with for) but not indexing
list_1 = (x[:2] for x in list_full)
list_2 = (x[2:] for x in list_full)
```

Or, in python 3, to easily iterate over your data without creating a list:

```
for a, b, *other in list_full:
    print("first:", a, b)
    print("other:", other)
```

Comment: I cannot use generators because I need the indexing. The list comprehension was the fastest one on a subset of data. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can try List comprehension,

```
list_1=[item[:2] for item in list_full]
list_2 = [item[2:] for item in list_full]
```

Based on some [documents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2849645/in-python-is-it-better-to-use-list-comprehensions-or-for-each-loops#answer-2849691) list comprehension is much faster than looping.

You can calculate time taken by both the method using `timeit`,

```
from timeit import default_timer as timer
start=timer()
list_1 = []
list_2 = []

for item in list_full:
    list_1.append(item[:2])
    list_2.append(item[2:])

print list_1
print list_2

end=timer()

print end-start #Takes 0.0002339
```

While using list comprehension ,

```
from timeit import default_timer as timer
start = timer()
list_1=[item[:2] for item in list_full]
list_2 = [item[2:] for item in list_full]

print list_1
print list_2

end = timer()

print end-start #gives 0.0002105
```

Comment: I tested on a small sample of data, and your answer is the fastest one. Thanks!

Comment: I tested on a bigger sample of data as suggested and using itertools proved to be faster. I will have in mind list comprehension for smaller subsets! :)