# How can I print a list of possible choices using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

for example if I have a list:

```
L = [3, 3]
```

I want to print:
the following available moves per index:

```
[[3, 0], [2, 0], [1, 0], [3, 1], [2, 1], [1, 1]]
```

any idea?

I tried `[[i for i in lst] for lst in list]`, but this didn't work

Comment: Can you expand a bit on the logic of how the input list is transformed intot he output list?

Comment: Shouldn't the output be [[0,0],[0,1],[0,2],[1,0],[1,1],[1,2],[2,0],[2,1],[2,2]] if you want to print the  available moves per index?

Comment: I'm giving the list L = [3, 3] from which I need to create the possible choices for each index for example for index 0 i should get [3, index 0], [2, index 0], [1, index 0] and so on for every index

Comment: @Pepelepiu Have you any attempt at a single for loop?

Comment: @cricket_007 no I tried [[i for i in lst] for lst in self.list] this didn't work

Answer (score 1):

is this what you had in mind

```
my_list = [3,3]
final_list = []
for i in range(0, my_list[0] + 1):
    for j in range(my_list[0], 0, -1):
        final_list.append([j, i])
print(final_list)
```

output:

```
[[3, 0], [2, 0], [1, 0], [3, 1], [2, 1], [1, 1], [3, 2], [2, 2], [1, 2], [3, 3], [2, 3], [1, 3]]
```

It has more results than you listed in the question, but it covers all the combinations

Comment: @Pepelepiu List-comprehension shouldn't be abused to solve every problem.

Comment: @Pepelepiu No, there's just no reason to get everything into a single line. Especially if you can't understand it

Comment: This should help I gues! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2849645/in-python-is-it-better-to-use-list-comprehensions-or-for-each-loops

Comment: not a big list comprehension guy, so not sure how to do my answer in list comprehension

Comment: I've posted the answer with list comprehension! Take a look!

Comment: @Pepelepiu if you want to find out how to use list comprehension, please kindly check my answer

Comment: @PoStevanusAndrianta Thank you, I will check that out

Comment: @The4thIceman no problem man, thanks so much for the response. I'm new to python, I have program in C and C++ and this language is so different.

Comment: @Pepelepiu I'm confused. This is not at all what you're asking for, but you're thanking for it. Huh?

Comment: @StefanPochmann I'm thanking for helping out. help is help regardless of the answer.

Comment: @Pepelepiu Ah. But it's misleading. Makes people think it's correct. If you just want to thank for effort, better say that and mention that it's not correct, so it's clear.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>>import itertools as it
>>> L
[3, 3]
>>> res = [[[i,j] for j in range(L[1])] for i in range(L[0],0,-1)]
>>> print [i for i in it.chain.from_iterable(res)]
[[3, 0], [3, 1], [3, 2], [2, 0], [2, 1], [2, 2], [1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2]]
```

Hope that answers your question!

Comment: Can simply be `range(L[1])`

Answer (score 1):

Um, none of the other answers produce the desired result. This does:

```
>>> L = [3, 3]
>>> [[m, i] for i, n in enumerate(L) for m in range(n, 0, -1)]
[[3, 0], [2, 0], [1, 0], [3, 1], [2, 1], [1, 1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use pythonic way

```
data = [3,3]
print([[a,b] for a in range(data[0]+1) for b in range(data[1]+1)])
```

the output will be

```
[[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [0, 3], [1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 0], [2, 1], [2, 2], [2, 3], [3, 0], [3, 1], [3, 2], [3, 3]]
```

**Edit**

i saw that you do not want a '0' in the first element, so just use `range(1,data[0]+1)`

```
data = [3,3]
print([[a,b] for a in range(1,data[0]+1) for b in range(data[1]+1)])
```

the output will be

```
[[1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 0], [2, 1], [2, 2], [2, 3], [3, 0], [3, 1], [3, 2], [3, 3]]
```