# In python, how to style a complicated list comprehension

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I'm working on applying what I've learned about list comprehensions and reading through Pep 8. I'm running into a stylistic dilemma. First, the code:

```
# Using nested for's and conditionals
for m, row in enumerate(board):
    for n, piece in enumerate(row):
        if (piece == self.color or piece == self.Color):
            print(m, n, piece)

# Using list comprehensions
[
    [
        print(m, n, piece)
        for n, piece in enumerate(row)
        if (piece == self.color or piece == self.Color)
    ]
    for m, row in enumerate(board)
]
```

To me, I would think Pep 8 sort of leans towards nested for's approach just because (to me) it looks slightly more intuitive. Maybe I'm not approaching the formatting of the list comprehension well enough though. That's the best I could think to format it while maintaining the 79 col preferred wrap.

I think I have a good grasp of list comprehensions at this point and they are definitely suitable for this application I think but...is it preferred to use list comprehensions just for the sake of using list comprehensions?

Maybe I just need to rethink my code architecture completely? I don't expect SO to make such a recommendation for this(!), but maybe some insight on which approach shown above would be better to look at for the  Pythonistas out there!

Edit: The recommended duplicate question (didn't see this pop up in the recommended dupes upon creating the question otherwise I wouldn't have asked! :D ) addresses this question perfectly. I guess I should have read up more on what was meant by "side-effects" of list comprehensions, as that definitely appears to be the case with my question.

[Here's the duplicate link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2849645/in-python-is-it-better-to-use-list-comprehensions-or-for-each-loops) in case the duplicate mark gets removed:

As always, thanks for the great answers SO!

Comment: It's not recommended to use list comprehensions for side-effects. Just use a loop.

Comment: The code you posted gives a syntax error because of the printing inside the list comprehension. You may have meant ```print [[(m,n,piece) for ... ]]```

Comment: @user55449 are you sure you are using the right version of python?

Comment: No, you're right. Maybe a Python 3 tag should be added.

Comment: If you hadn't written it, which would you prefer to read?

Comment: That's my bad; yes, I am using Python3. Definitely useful information!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think above method has better readability.
And list comprehensions generate list not for doing something... it's just side-effect.

```
for m, row in enumerate(board):
    for n, piece in enumerate(row):
        if piece == self.color or piece == self.Color:
            print(m, n, piece)
```

It's enough.

or you must want to use list comprehensions, then generate list and print it like this.

```
result = [
    [
        (m, n, piece)
        for n, piece in enumerate(row)
        if piece == self.color or piece == self.Color
    ] 
    for m, row in enumerate(board)
]
print (result)
```

or

```
for res in result:
    m, n, piece = res
    print (m, n, piece)
```