# Print elements in comprehension as soon as they are computed

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Suppose I wish to compute and view the result of a list comprehension that takes a while to compute but returns only a small number of results; for instance (artificial example),

```
L = [x for x in range(100000000) if x<10]; print(L)
```

Is there a simple way to print these elements as soon as they are computed, rather than all at the end? One can write a decorator to do it:

```
import sys

def print_as_computed(gen):
    try:
        while True:
            v = next(gen)
            print v
            sys.stdout.flush()
            yield v
    except StopIteration:
        pass

L1 = list(print_as_computed(x for x in range(10000000) if x<10))
```

but I am wondering if there is a builtin to do it, or a more standard/Pythonic way.

Comment: That built-in way you're looking for is a `for` loop. List comprehensions create lists. If you need to do something while creating that list, use a loop instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Python, is it better to use list comprehensions or for-each loops?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2849645/in-python-is-it-better-to-use-list-comprehensions-or-for-each-loops)

Answer (score 3):

If you want the equivalent of your generator function with an explicit `for` statement, but with the conciseness of a comprehension, that's what generator expressions are for:

```
L = (x for x in range(100000000) if x<10)
for value in L: print(value)
```

If you really want to cram the `print` into the expression, you can, although it's definitely not idiomatic or readable. For example:

```
L = (print(x) or x for x in range(100000000) if x<10)
L1 = list(L)
```

Since `print(x)` always returns `None`, `print(x) or x` is always `x`. (Again, you shouldn't actually do this—but it's worth working through how it works until you understand it.)

---

For Python 2, if you're not using `from __future__ import print_function`, if you want to do the same hack, you also have to create a `print`-like function, because you can't use a statement inside an expression:

```
def printify(s):
    print s

L = (printify(x) or x for x in range(100000000) if x<10)
```

Comment: Thanks, very good advice! I assume it's `print(value)` in the first method. Also, if I understand correctly, the first method does not return the list of values, right? They are printed and then discarded.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Good catch on the `print` argument. Anyway, neither one _returns_ anything. The first one prints, the second one also stores values in a list, but you can only return values with a `return` statement.

Comment: Sorry, wrong word. What I meant is: after my original suggestion or your second method, L1 contains a list with the valid values. After your first method, L contains nothing and I have no way to retrieve the computed values for later use in my code.

Comment: (Also, just for reference: method 2 is python3 only -- in Python 2 print is a special instruction and does not have a return value.)

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Sure, but in Python 2, you can trivially write a function that just `print`s its arguments, and call that instead.