# How to convert a list comprehension to a nested loop?

Tags: python

I was looking through some Python code and found this line in the code:

```
data = [[int(x) for x in list] for list in values]
```

This code basically converts strings to integers in the values of the nested list. For example:

```
values = [['8', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0'], ['9', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0']]
```

The output becomes:

```
data = [[8, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0], [9, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0]]
```

At this moment the for loop is a nested for loop, it looks "complicated", what if I wanted to convert this into a "regular" for loops, so it becomes easier to follow but still does the same job?
How would that code look like?

Comment: If you look up list comprehension you'll see plenty of examples of how to do this

Comment: [In Python, is it better to use list comprehensions or for-each loops?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2849645/in-python-is-it-better-to-use-list-comprehensions-or-for-each-loops) might be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 data = [[int(x) for x in list] for list in values]
```

this snippet is a list comprehension, to use a for loop you have to do:

```
data[]
for list in values:
    y = []
    for x in list:
         y.append(int(x))
    data.append(y)
```

Answer (score 0):

Find explanation in the comments

```py
#data = [[int(x) for x in list] for list in values]  
values = [['8', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0'], ['9', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0'], ['10', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0'], ['11', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'], ['12', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'], ['13', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'], ['14', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'], ['15', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'], ['16', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '2', '3'], ['17', '1', '1', '2', '0', '1', '1', '0'], ['18', '1', '0', '0', '2', '1', '1', '2']] 

# it is similar to 
final_list = []
for list_ in values:
    # iterate over the values
    temp = []
    for c in list_:
        temp.append(int(c))
    final_list.append(temp) # be cautious you can caught with shallow copy sometime, safe side use final_list.append(temp.copy())
    
print(final_list)
```

```
[[8, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0], [9, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0], [10, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0], [11, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [12, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [13, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [14, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [15, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [16, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 3], [17, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1, 1, 0], [18, 1, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 2]]
```

Answer (score 0):

the current loop architecture will look like:

```
data = []
for word in values:
    nested_list = []
    for x in word:
        nested_list.append(int(x))
    data.append(nested_list)
```

I would suggest using list comprehension and trying to avoid naming variables with **[Reserved Keywords](https://realpython.com/lessons/reserved-keywords/)** like list, if, elif

I see there're already ready answers, but tried)